# Sass deep map-get throws *map* sn't a valid CSS value

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm pretty new to Sass and learning a lot trying out a practice project. But I'm running into a strange issue that I can't seem to find the answer for anywhere. I'm hoping it isn't something small that I am just glancing over. I have a map set up for background images per page. I created a mixin that I place in each pages partial that calls a function to grab the image url based on props passed in (the function was built of multiple examples I read through). But when I try to compile it throws an error that lists the map out and says it isn't a valid CSS value. I can't seem to figure out what is going on.

Map:

```
$bg-images: (
  home: (
    desktop: url(../assets/home/background-home-desktop.jpg),
    tablet: url(../assets/home/background-home-tablet.jpg),
    mobile: url(../assets/home/background-home-mobile.jpg)
  ),
    destination: (
    desktop: url(../assets/destination/background-destination-desktop.jpg),
    tablet: url(../assets/destination/background-destination-tablet.jpg),
    mobile: url(../assets/destination/background-destination-mobile.jpg)
  ),
  crew: (
    desktop: url(../assets/crew/background-crew-desktop.jpg),
    tablet: url(../assets/crew/background-crew-tablet.jpg),
    mobile: url(../assets/crew/background-crew-mobile.jpg)
  ),
  technology: (
    desktop: url(../assets/technology/background-technology-desktop.jpg),
    tablet: url(../assets/technology/background-technology-tablet.jpg),
    mobile: url(../assets/technology/background-technology-mobile.jpg)
  )
);
```

Mixin

```
@mixin background($page, $bg) {
  width: 100%;
  background: get-bg-img($bg-images, $page, $bg);
  background-size: cover;
};
```

Function

```
@function get-bg-img($page, $keys...) {
  @each $key in $keys {
    $page: map-get($page, $key);
  };
  
  @return $page;
};
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong that would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Your code seems to work fine when I try it. How are you including your `@mixin`?

Comment: This is the include for the mixin: ```@include background(home, desktop);``` Currently I switched from that function to a little messy looking ```map-get(map-get($bg-images, $page), $bg);``` and that is working fine. I'm not sure what is going on with it

Comment: Yeah... I think the problem comes from your compiler because your code is perfectly valid.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, wondering if the compiler is different for those who have it working...